# How do I see logs on parse-server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Parse had a nice development command utility where you could read and stream logs.

Heroku has that, but it shows only Heroku logs, not Parse logs.

Is there some way to see a `console.log` or `console.error` statement now that we're all switching over to parse-server?

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I'm having the same issue but on Amazon. It seems that they should show up in Parse Dashboard but they aren't there for me either.

Answer (score 7):

If you use `PM2`, it is really easy to see logs.

For my project, I have parse-server and parse-dashboard running on my server.
Here is the PM2 config I use for them:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "script": "parse-server",
            "args": "config/server.json",
            "log_file": "logs/server.log",
            "error_file": "logs/server-error.log",
            "log_date_format" : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z",
            "instances": 1, 
            "watch": true,
            "ignore_watch": ["cloud", "logs"],
            "env": {
                "VERBOSE": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "script": "parse-dashboard",
            "args": "--config config/dashboard.json",
            "log_file": "logs/dashboard.log",
            "error_file": "logs/dashboard-error.log",
            "log_date_format" : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z",
            "instances": 1,
            "watch": true,
            "ignore_watch": ["cloud", "logs"]
        }
    ]
}
```

In my case, it is the `"VERBOSE": "1"` argument that allows me to see all the queries executed by parse-server.

If you want to see the logs of both parse-server and parse-dashboard, you then only have to type `pm2 logs`.

In my configuration, parse-server and parse-dashboard are installed globally (`npm install -g parse-server` and `npm install -g parse-dashboard`).

Comment: what do you mean by PM2?

Answer (score 4):

If you have Heroku CLI installed you can run these lines inside your project

```
heroku logs
```

for the last 100 lines or

```
heroku logs --tail
```

to show logs in real time

Comment: Yep, that's what I've been doing. No logs! Plz help ;)

Answer (score 3):

The latest versions of Parse dashboard have Logs page out of the box

[image]

Comment: Oooh that is nice.

Comment: this is what i get at the moment: `When you start using Cloud Code, your logs will show up here.
Learn more
`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about how you can see logs on Heroku, but i am able to see logs locally. What you need to do is when your run your application using  command => node app.js then you will be able to see all console.log(""); statements in the console.

If you want you check this link . How to setup Parse on local machine.

https://www.webniraj.com/2016/01/31/parse-com-setting-up-the-open-source-parse-api-server/.

I hope this helps.Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this, I am looking for a way to see logs while my code is running on Heroku as well though.

Comment: I can see some logs there. But not everything it seems. When I saw an "authorization error" while testing and went to the console, I saw other erros but no indication that someone had been denied access.

Comment: Console.log has issues sometimes, rather use console.info

Answer (score 0):

here are 2 ways, in case of selfhosted parse-server:

### #1 view logs by url

- create a symbolic link of your log-folder to `/public/logs`
- add this middleware:

```
app.get(/^\/logs*/,(req,res,next) => {
  if( req.url == '/logs/' || req.url == '/logs' )
    return res.redirect('/logs/parse-server.info.'+new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10))
  if( req.url.match(/parse-server\./) )
    res.set('content-type','text/plain') // lets hint the browser for a logfile
  next()
})

// *TODO* please run basic-auth middleware on /logs url
```

> BOOM...now surfing to '/logs' will always redirect to the latest log-url. 
>   You can just modify the dates to go back in time.

### #2 view realtime logs

see this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-logio

Comment: #2 not working i got this error
``` { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6689
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1085:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6689 }
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6689
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1085:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6689 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use request.log.info() and request.log.error() and they will be show in the parse dashboard

[Cloud Code function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACqN3.png)

[Log on Parse dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXPT0.png)